# Проблема с отправкой почты в Laravel - mail::send возвращает null

Tags: laravel5

Такая ситуация: Laravel 5.5, ОS: Linux
Пытаюсь отправить сообщение с формы.  Драйвер пробовал mail и sendmail. Сообщения, вроде бы как   отправляется, но на почту не приходят. Сам метод mail::send возвращает null, но без ошибок. 
Я для отладки поставил драйвер log. Сообщения в логи добавляются, все нормально. Т.е. работает, но mail:send все-равно null возвращает. Не могу понять...

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772531/laravel-mail-sending-email-but-returning-false

Судя по тому, что пишут здесь этот метод не должен возвращать ничего дельного. Там же написано и что использовать, если нужно собрать информацию о не доставленных отправлениях. 
пример:

```
if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
    $errors = 'Failed to send password reset email, please try again.';
}
```

Comment: В том-то и дело, что у меня Mail::failures() выдает пустой массив [], т.е. как-бы все норм. Да и выглядит как норм, ведь сообщения в логи идут, если драйвер log использовать. А как только переключаю на живую отправку - на реальные адреса, не идут. Пробовал 2 разных адрееса.

Comment: Может это не в Ларе дело. Я в селе сижу на мобильном интернете, причем edge, а не 3g. Мож. дело в связи?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. Mail::send() действительно не возвращает bool. Теперь проверяю с помощью Mail::failures()

Comment: Станислав, рекомендую завести себе удалённый примитивный сервер из разряда условно-бесплатных (для начала) -- там можно будет быть уверенным, что он отправляет и принимает в дата-центре так как надо.